# F_GETPIPE_SZ returns -1 in C

Tags: pipe, c, fifo

Why would F_GETPIPE_SZ return -1? It sounds like an error, but I can't find any mention of what error it is, or, more importantly, what I'm supposed to do to not get the error.

I'm running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi, for what it's worth. I haven't tried the code on my desktop Debian yet. As far as I can tell, I'm following the textbook F_GETPIPE_SZ example. Am I missing something?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd, pipesize;
  fd = mkfifo("/tmp/audio-fifo",0666);
  //  fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, 4096);
  pipesize = fcntl(fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ);
  printf("Pipe size: %d\n", pipesize);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mkfifo` return 0 on success and -1 on failure. While `fnctl` expects the first argument is a file descriptor.

Comment: in other words, `mkfifo ...; fd = open("/tmp/audio-fifo", ...)`

Comment: Try by checking `errno` (using `#include <errno.h>`) directly after `fcntl()`. But the error value is probably `EINVAL`. Assuming `mkfifo()` was successful, you tried to get the pipe size of file descriptor `0`. `mkfifo()` creates a file system entry for a fifo, it does not open a file descriptor to the fifo.

Comment: Thanks all, I see now why it's wrong. So I simply use the same path string in mkfifo and open?

Answer (score 1):

`mkfifo` will just create the special file for you. It will return either `0` on success or an `errno` if an error occoured.

What you have to do after you created the pipe using `mkfifo` is open that file with `open`. After that you will have a valid file descriptor to pass `fnctl` (as long as none of these functions returned an error!).

So basically what you are missing is the `open` command.

Answer (score 0):

To follow **Nidhoegger**'s answer, here's a complete example

Error handling is left as an exercise to the reader (failed calls will largely return `-1` and should be checked after `mkfifo` and before working with `fd`)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>  // not required

#define PATH "/tmp/audio-fifo"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;

    // create a fifo at PATH
    mkfifo(PATH, 0644);
    fd = open(PATH, O_RDWR);
    printf("Pipe size: %d\n", fcntl(fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ));

    // resize the pipe with fcntl
    fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, 4096);
    printf("Pipe size: %d\n", fcntl(fd, F_GETPIPE_SZ));

    return 0;
}
```

```
% gcc test.c && ./a.out
Pipe size: 65536
Pipe size: 4096
```